# Repeating Local Notifications at specific intervals

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, usernotifications

Is it possible to have a notification repeat at specific intervals? For example, Remind me to do something on Monday to Friday (from 9:00am to 6:00pm)?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule local notifications for the specific time, date, weekday, and also specify to be repeated or not.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app) is a comprehensive document provided by Apple that describes how to do it.

If I'm not mistaken, You mean to schedule notification for a continuous period of time, If so, It does not make sense and it's not possible.

But you can schedule multiple notifications for different times of a weekday based on your need.